# angular.js:13920 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following error when trying to read the following json and mapping in html

js:

```
searhController.orderlogs.results = JSON.stringify(response.data);
```

angular:

```
<tr ng-hide="searhController.searching" ng-repeat="log in searhController.orderlogs.results">
                    <td>{{log.idTransaction}}</td>
                   <!-- <td>{{log.amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.clientName}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.created}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.currency}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.discountedAmount}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.lastUpdate}}</td>
                    <td>{{log.orderId}}</td> -->
                </tr>
```

JSON:

```
 [{"idTransaction":2081101,"amount":34990.0,"clientName":"Payment hub","created":"ene 12, 2015","currency":"CLP","discountedAmount":34990.0,"lastUpdate":"ene 12, 2015","orderId":"1421094905114","productDescription":"total: 1 item(s)","fop":{"nameFop":"CAT_FAKE"},"application":{"idApplication":10001,"nameApplication":"TEST APPLICATION"},"transactionStatus":{"nameTransactionStatus":"Waiting for reply"},"transactionByFop":{"settled_amount":0.0,"installments_amount":0.0,"installments_number":0}}]
```

Error:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: log in searhController.orderlogs.results, Duplicate key: string:a, Duplicate value: a
```

Comment: Your posted JSON is not valid... There are several errors. Use a online Validator or a browser plugin. You shouldn't stringify your JSON use JSON.parse(response.data)

Comment: ok but according to several pages json is valid

Comment: Than these pages are not good or you didn't validate the JSON you've posted. Because a line like this "transactionByFop":"settled_amount":0.0, is 100% invalid.
I used https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ for validation.

Comment: apology, copy bad json, thanks for your time

Comment: It would be nice if you would then provide the correct JSON by using the edit function. Users stumbling over your question will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr ng-hide="searhController.searching" ng-repeat="log in searhController.orderlogs.results track by $index">
                <td>{{log.idTransaction}}</td>
               <!-- <td>{{log.amount}}</td>
                <td>{{log.clientName}}</td>
                <td>{{log.created}}</td>
                <td>{{log.currency}}</td>
                <td>{{log.discountedAmount}}</td>
                <td>{{log.lastUpdate}}</td>
                <td>{{log.orderId}}</td> -->
            </tr>
```

just add `track by $index` to the end of your`ng-repeat`. Right now two objects in your collection are equal, and `ng-repeat` tracks by value by default. Adding `track by $index` will track by the position of the object.

Comment: Please up vote the correct answers and check one off as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not valid an you should Format it properly because it is not that small -- a one-liner is quite bad.

This would be valid:

```
{  
   "transaction":{  
      "idTransaction":2081101,
      "amount":34990.0,
      "clientName":"Payment hub",
      "created":"ene 12, 2015",
      "currency":"CLP",
      "discountedAmount":34990.0,
      "lastUpdate":"ene 12, 2015",
      "orderId":"1421094905114",
      "productDescription":"total: 1 item(s)",
      "fop":{  
         "nameFop":"CAT_FAKE"
      },
      "application":"",
      "idApplication":10001,
      "nameApplication":"TEST APPLICATION"
   },
   "transactionStatus":{  
      "nameTransactionStatus":"Waiting for reply"
   },
   "transactionByFop":"",
   "settled_amount":0.0,
   "installments_amount":0.0,
   "installments_number":0
}
```

What have I done?

You had two empty attributes, that weren't filled with any data and destroying you JSON like:

```
[INVALID] "attr1" : "attr2" : "valueOfAttr2",
[VALID]   "attr1" : "", "attr2":"valueOfAttr2"
```

And you had more than one Root element therefore it wasn't valid JSON.
Try it with the correct data and test if it's working.

Comment: I worked was an issue that should add index, and sets the result, 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
ng-repeat="log in searhController.orderlogs.results track by $index">
```

Comment: That would be nice. For me and users finding this problem while searching :).